# Symfony 5 form returning null

Tags: php, symfony

Hey I'm trying to make a typical post in symfony using forms but sadly it's not working. I have no freaking idea what's going on in here.

I have my controller:

```
...
/**
 * @FOSRest\Post("/product")
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @throws \Psr\Cache\InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form = $this->formFactory->createNamed('product', ProductType::class, $product);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
```

And the form type

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * ProductType.
 */
final class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('price', NumberType::class)
            ->add('currency', TextType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'method' => 'POST',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the entity:

```
...
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="currency", type="string", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Value cant be empty")
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 * @Serializer\Type("string")
 * @Serializer\Expose()

 */
private $currency;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrency(): string
{
    return $this->currency;
}

/**
 * @param string $currency
 * @return self
 */
public function setCurrency(string $currency): self
{
    $this->currency = $currency;
    return $this;
}
...
```

For some reason `$this->formFactory->createNamed` badly doesn't want to work and returns me:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
> Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\UninitializedPropertyException:
> "The method "App\Entity\Product::getCurrency()" returned "null", but
> expected type "string". Did you forget to initialize a property or to
> make the return type nullable using "?string"?"

I have totally no idea what the heck is going on... Could someone be my Obi-wan and help me?

Cheers

Comment: What don't you understand?  What do you expect the value of currency to be without initialization?  What do you expect a return type of string to do if something besides a string is returned?

Comment: Well, first of all validation here doesn't trigger, form should return error telling that field is empty, when its not send. Also, even If I send post with all the params, form says that... it's null? I'm not really catching it. Mind telling me how to initialize it? Also.. well Im getting same error when I go with default value for currency, it still says its null

Comment: What makes you think the error is happening on submission?  How do values get into your form in the first place?  Have you looked at the chapter in the php docs on objects?

Comment: Its not happening on submit, its happening during creating named form... I dont really know how does symfony fill this form, I can only suspect

Comment: Do you suspect that the form is calling getCurrency() to get the currency value?  Have you considered what "Did you forget to initialize a property or to make the return type nullable using "?string"?"" part of the error message might indicate?  Focus young Luke or the force might leave you.